# Pandas `bdate_range' returns list of dates that include weekends

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas version 1.2.3 to generate a list of business days within a business quarter, 'BQ'.

Unfortunately, the following implementation seems to generate dates that include weekends:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dates = pd.bdate_range(
    start=datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), 
    end=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
    freq='BQ'
    )
```

With the above implementation, one of the dates within the defined bounds above is '2017-12-31', which is a Sunday?

My inputs appear to be consistent with what the function signature expects as per the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html.

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Thank you.

Comment: `bdate_range()` does not accept `end_date` as a parameter. When I replace `end_date` with just `end`, I get the expected output with 12/29/2017 being the quarter end.

Comment: sorry thats a typo - have changed now. It is strange because I get 2017/12/31

Comment: That is weird. My only guess would be you have an older version of pandas?

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, I'm not getting `2017-12-31`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dates = pd.bdate_range(
    start=datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), 
    end=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
    )
```

Another option:

```
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
    from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

    us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
    dates = pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2015, 1, 1),end=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), freq=us_bd)
```

Comment: I think you meant to put "2017-12-31" at the top of your answer.  Also, there is actually a difference between your two options, as `bdate_range()` includes holidays, while the second option will exclude US holidays.

Comment: I added US holidays because if it's to find business days, then other holidays should also be included apart from weekends. E.g. no business remain open on 25th Dec, even if it's on weekday.